# Online groups for Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning, online-resources

As you can imagine, it is much easier to study sth in a group, where you will have a lot of interaction if you want, than alone! There has been formed a Facebook group on Measure Theory recently. Do you know of anything else of the sort on the web? Thanks